# Last cell with dynamic column name

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following table and for a given column name, I want a formula to extract the last cell of the given column.

[image]

So far I have found out how to get the last value of a given column:
`=INDEX( FILTER( B:B , NOT( ISBLANK( B:B ) ) ) , ROWS( FILTER( B:B , NOT( ISBLANK( B:B ) ) ) ) )`

And how to get the column number by comparing cell entries (e.g. 'BTC/AUD'):
`=match('BTC/AUD',$1:$1,0)`

What formula can I use to get the latest value for any given column name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
=vlookup(1E+100,E11:G14,match(E16,E11:G11,0))
```